# Hibernate saveAndFlush not persisted when application exception is thrown

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I hope someone has come across this issue:

In the service layer I am catching an exception and in the catch block I want to save a record in the database calling `saveAndFlush`  and then throwing the application exception. The issue is that the save and flush doesn't persist the record and the transaction seems to rollback.

The code is something like that:

```
catch(SomeException e) {
   repoClass.saveAndFlush(entity);
   throw new ApplicationException();
}
```

Any thoughts?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because spring will roll back the transaction if the code throws any `RuntimeException`, `ApplicationException` is a `RuntimeException` hence `saveAndFlush` not working (Transaction rolled back).

In your case you have to throw a `UserDefinedException` instead of the `RuntimeException`

sample

```
public class UserDefinedException extends Exception {

}
```